# Laravel | Update Query return " [{"laboratory":"Boulanger"}]" as value instead of "Boulanger"

Tags: laravel-5, pdo

I have created a hook function in one of my controller to update a field after submitting the form.

The hook should populate the field "laboratory" of the "orders_detail" database with the name of a laboratory.

```
/* POPULATE the laboratory FIELD */
DB::table('orders_detail')->where('id',$id)->first();
/* dd($id); */

/* REQUESTED VALUE IN ARRAY :   "ordersdetail-productname" => array:1 [▼ 0 => "1" ] : */

$productname = $_REQUEST['ordersdetail-productnameID'][0];
/* dd($productnameID); **RETURN VALUE "1"** */

/* QUERY : select laboratories.laboratory FROM products LEFT JOIN laboratories ON products.laboratoryID = laboratories.id WHERE products.id = productnameID : */

$laboratory = DB::table('products')
                ->join('laboratories', 'products.laboratoryID', '=', 'laboratories.id')
                ->selectRaw('laboratories.laboratory')
                ->where('products.id', '=', $productnameID)
                ->get();

/* dd($laboratory); **RETURNED ARRAY 
        Collection {#3536 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => {#3534 ▼
              +"laboratory": "Boulanger"
            }
          ]
        }** */

/* UPDATE THE laboratory FIELD WITH THE RETURNED VALUE */
DB::table('orders_detail')->where('orderID', '=', $id)
->update(['laboratory'=> $laboratory]);
```

How can I get rid of **"laboratory": "Boulanger"** and just keep **Boulanger** which is the name of the laboratory I want to update the field "laboratory" with.

Thanks for your expertise.

Cheers, Marc

Comment: use `->first()` instead of `->get();` since you are expecting one laboratory. Then what would be the output of `dd($laboratory)` ?

Comment: @ Ijas

{#3534 ▼
  +"laboratory": "Boulanger"
}

Comment: then `$laboratory->laboratory` will give the value "Boulanger"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your **laboratory** query as,

```
$laboratory = DB::table('products')
                ->join('laboratories', 'products.laboratoryID', '=', 'laboratories.id')
                ->selectRaw('laboratories.laboratory')
                ->where('products.id', '=', $productnameID)
                ->first();
```

And `$laboratory->laboratory` will give you the expected value.

Update as,

```
/* UPDATE THE laboratory FIELD WITH THE RETURNED VALUE */

if($laboratory->laboratory) {
    DB::table('orders_detail')
       ->where('orderID', $id)
       ->update(['laboratory'=> $laboratory->laboratory]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time, When I get the laboratory value I'm updating the appropriate row and column with the following code :

DB::table('orders_detail')->where('orderID', '=', $id)
->update(['laboratory'=> $laboratory]);

Where can I set $laboratory->laboratory ?

Comment: thanks a lot, it is working ! You are great ! But I forgot that we can have different laboratories ! :

Now according to the ordered products, we can have different laboratories, for example :

    $productname = $_REQUEST['ordersdetail-productnameID'];
     dd($productnameID);
    
 return the array containing the 2 productnameIDs :
  
    array:2 [▼
      0 => "26"
      1 => "1"
    ]

Comment: This 2 products are produced in different laboratories, so I need to apply the following rule :


Table 'laboratories' :
 
 id  | laboratory
 1   | Boulanger
 2   | Chocolat
 3   | Magasin
 4   | Cuisine

Table 'orders_details
    
    id  | orderID | producttypeID | productnameID | laboratory
    225 | 206     | 4             | 26            | Cuisine 
    226 | 206     | 1             | 1             | Boulanger


orders_detail.producttypeID = laboratories.id and populate the field 'orders_detail.laboratory' with the values of 'laboratory.laboratory'.

Comment: If the question above is resolved, could you please accept it and Ask a new one ? then It can be resolved separately .

Comment: Thanks a lot again already for your time and expertise. Would appreciate if you could have a look at the following question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613416/laravel-update-query-with-data-from-array

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $laboratory = DB::table('products')
            ->join('laboratories', 'products.laboratoryID', '=', 'laboratories.id')
            ->where('products.id', '=', $productnameID)
            ->pluck('laboratories.laboratory');
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant, laboratory vanished but I still have [" and "] which I would like to get rid of. Table is updated with :  ["Boulanger"]. Any clue why ?

Comment: This is how ```pluck()``` returns result. Not very sure but try ```value()``` in place of ```pluck()```. See if you are getting desired result.